# Finding duplicate properties inside two lists

Tags: c#

I have two lists, each list is of type "Node". So I have a StartNodeList and an EndNodeList.

Each Node consists of 3 properties of type Double... X, Y and Z.

The StartNodeList and EndNodeList currently contain Nodes with identical property values.

The output I need is a single list of type Node that contains only Nodes with unique property values (i.e. no duplicate Nodes).

I have tried all manner of foreach loops and comparison operators that I can think of with varying levels of success with nothing working perfectly, and several hours of researching the problem online hasn't helped.

Could someone please help me toward a solution?

```
 while (selector.MoveNext())
        {
            Beam beam = selector.Current as Beam;

            if (beam != null)
            {

                Node nodeEnd = new Node();
                nodeEnd.x = beam.EndPoint.X;
                nodeEnd.y = beam.EndPoint.Y;
                nodeEnd.z = beam.EndPoint.Z;


                Node nodeStart = new Node();
                nodeStart.x = beam.StartPoint.X;
                nodeStart.y = beam.StartPoint.Y;
                nodeStart.z = beam.StartPoint.Z;

                Member member = new Member() { member_start = nodeStart, member_end = nodeEnd, member_id = 1 };

                memberList.Add(member);

                nodeEndList.Add(nodeEnd);
                nodeStartList.Add(nodeStart);

                memberNumdber++;
            }

        }

        Console.WriteLine(nodeStartList.Count());
        Console.ReadLine();

        int count = nodeStartList.Count();

        foreach(Node i in nodeEndList)
        {
            nodeListSorted = EqualityComparer.Compare(i, nodeStartList);
        }
```

public static class EqualityComparer
{

```
    public static List<Node> Compare(Node node, List<Node> list)
    {
        List<Node> output = new List<Node>();
        output.Add(node);

        foreach(Node i in list)
        {

            if (node.x.Equals(i.x) && node.y.Equals(i.y) && node.z.Equals(i.z))
            {

            }

            else
            {
                output.Add(i);
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. Ensure sample data is in the [mcve] _in code_. Make sure you are explicit about the _exact_ output you want.

Comment: please share the reproducible example with the code you are using. Sample data will help to resolve the issue. Also, share the output expected from the sampled data.

Comment: It's much easier for you and us if you include the code instead of _describing_ it. I honestly don't understand why many users choose to do the latter.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using linq. you can use `Union` which Produces the set union of two sequences and `Any` which determines whether any element of a sequence exists based onj the given condition.

```
var uniqueList = list1.Where(el => !list2.Any(l2 => l2.x == el.x && l2.y == el.y && l2.z == e.z)).Union(List2);.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks. This also still results in some duplicates... {"nodes":{"1":{"x":0,"y":20000,"z":0},"2":{"x":0,"y":15000,"z":0},"3":{"x":0,"y":10000,"z":0},"4":{"x":0,"y":5000,"z":0},"5":{"x":0,"y":0,"z":0},"6":{"x":0,"y":0,"z":5000},"7":{"x":0,"y":5000,"z":5000},"8":{"x":0,"y":10000,"z":5000},"9":{"x":0,"y":15000,"z":5000},"10":{"x":0,"y":20000,"z":5000},"11":{"x":0,"y":15000,"z":5000},"12":{"x":0,"y":10000,"z":5000},"13":{"x":0,"y":5000,"z":5000},"14":{"x":0,"y":0,"z":5000}}}